# Casting array to different data-type before reading causes intermittent issues

Tags: cuda

I have an int array in global memory. In order to try and read from global memory less often, I have been experimenting with reading using datatypes that are 64 bits and then using the high or low 32 bits as needed. For example, this gets the 3rd and 4th ints from the array:

```
__device__ void func1(int* arr)
{
    unsigned long long int val = *((unsigned long long int *) &arr[3]);

    // Now operate on the individual ints
}
```

Using this method to retrieve ints gives me undefined behavior, even though it seems like this should work. When it does work, reading values this way is quite a bit faster than individual integer reads. Has anyone run across this problem before?

Comment: CUDA has built in vector types int2 and int4 which would be better for this. The compiler understands the alignment of these and will safely generates 64 bit or 128 bit load instructions.

Comment: Given the same conditions, reading into an int2 or int4 generates the same undefined behavior.

Comment: the idea is you don't read into an int2 or int4, you read a whole structure, which generates the optimal load instruction. After loading you can cast to an integral type and fiddle with bits to your hearts content.

Answer (score 1):

Quantities like to be aligned by their size.  I'm not sure how cuda handles what you're doing and its possible that it's environment specific, but your use of:

```
*((unsigned long long int *) &arr[3])
```

Assuming `arr` is 8 byte aligned, is taking an 8 byte quantity that is only 4 byte aligned.  This happens of course because:

```
arr = 8n           // n is an integer
sizeof(int) = 4

&arr[3] = 8n + 3*4 // simplifies to 8(n+1) + 4
```

I know you will run into issues if you try to do the same thing on a processor using 32 bit and 16 bit integers (though I've never tried it with 64 and 32 bit ones).

You will need to homebrew some sort of accessor deal that figures out where the piece of data you are trying to access is.  Consider the following situation, similar to yours:

```
int get32BitValueFrom(unsigned long long int longArray[], int index)
{
    // get the 64 bit int containing the 32 bit int we want
    unsigned long long int value = longarray[index >> 1];

    // if we wanted an odd index, return the high order 32 bits
    // otherwise return the low order 32 bits
    return (int) ((index & 1) ? (value >> 32) : (value));
}
```

Edit: I know you're using cuda and I know to avoid branching, but I'm sure there is a way to write equivalent code using some sort of bitwise or mathematical trick that accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: The GPU hardware requires all memory accesses to be aligned to the width of the access ("natural alignment"). An unsigned long long int must therefore be aligned to an 8-byte boundary. Misaligned accesses cause undefined behavior; in the case of loads random data is returned. If you build your code for sm_1x, the Open64 frontend is used. Open64 can warn you about these situations if you add the following to your nvcc commandline: -Xopencc -Wcast-align

Comment: So, I assume that aligning the array to 8-byte boundaries requires knowing the start of the original array? While annoying, it doesn't sound bad to keep track of, so I'll have to try this.

Comment: It would be easiest to just pass the data via an array of unsigned long long int, or alternatively an array of uint2 (which also has an 8-byte alignment). Otherwise you will have to check alignment at run time. If you want to keep the current approach of passing in an array of unsigned int, compositing an unsigned long long int will likely be fine performancewise unless your code is compute-limited.